# How to remove login page of android webview navigation after the the user is logged in?

Tags: android, authentication, webview, user-management

I have a Webview in which there is a user management system. After the user is logged in, it is redirected to dashboard but if the user presses the back button it comes back to login page where the user has to relogin to view dashboard.

My activity is also asking if the user wants to exit from the activity when the user presses the back button on the first page. I want the user to skip the login page if he/she is already logged in and exit from the app.

Comment: Please give us some more details like Do you want that when user press back button in DashBoard screen then app should close by skipping login screen?

Comment: Please check update...

Comment: When you call DashBoard activity using intent from WebView simply add finish at the end. eg. Intent i=new Intent(this,Dashboard.class);  startActivity(i); finish();

Comment: @Mayur_07 Sir... Everything is happening in the same Webview and in my project there is only one activity that has Webview. Login is done from same webview and dashboard is displayed in the same webview

Comment: That means you just need to skip login screen if user is already logged in. And if user press back in other screen then it should go on previous page...right?

Comment: @Mayur_07 Yes sir... thats it

Comment: Does my answer works for you?

Comment: @Mayur_07 Sir, Actually your technique is quite good but I have separate class for WebViewClient and it is hard to go with that. Is it possible for you to implement the same using a separate WebViewClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per I understand, you need to skip the login screen and exit if user press back button in DashBoard Screen and he/she is already logged in. If user press back on another page then it should go to previous link. Also you have only one activity which is WebView.

So to implement this functionality you need url of both login page and dashboard page. You need to track whether user is logged in or not.

eg.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String LOGIN_PAGE_URL = "<Your Login Page URL>";
    private final String DASHBOARD_PAGE_URL = "<Your DashBoard Page URL>";
    WebView webView;
    private boolean isAlreadyLoggedIn;      //by default it is false

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.loadUrl( < Your URL >);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    if (url.contains(LOGIN_PAGE_URL) && isAlreadyLoggedIn) {
                        // User is already logged in so show exit dialog and exit if user press yes
                        // <Your Dialog Code>
                        // call finish(); when user press yes
                    }
                    else if (url.contains(DASHBOARD_PAGE_URL)){
                        /* if this is true then user is logged in because user will be redirected to
                        DashBoard link only if he entered valid credentials.

                        Now change our flag to true so next time when user is redirected to login screen
                        then the first condition will get true and the exit dialog will be shown.
                         */
                        isAlreadyLoggedIn=true;
                    }
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a sample code, so make changes in your code as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityforResult else put activity.finish() in activity which contains webview so it will open home page instead of login page.